# javascript closure from function's parameter is not reflected when it is updated

Tags: javascript, closures

I tried to implement a small connect function. It should take an object in parameter and put them into an function. My expectation the latest object should be used always. Looks like it's not true.

```
let store = { type: 'initial' };

console.log(store);

function connect(param) {
  const connected2 = function (fn) {

    return function () {
      return fn(param);
    }
  };
  return connected2;
}

function execute(store) {
  console.log(store);
}

const connected = connect(store)(execute);

connected(); // console => { type: 'initial' }
store = {type: 'updated'};
connected(); // console { type: 'initial' } but expect updated
```

Comment: `connect` looks like a weird curried functions which is lazily evaluated. Rewrite it to `const connect = param => fn => () => fn(param);` since you already rely on ES2015 syntax.

Comment: the real code used ES2015 syntax and it works in the same way as provided example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable in `execute` is an argument, i.e. a local variable. It doesn't refer to the global `store` variable.

Either remove the argument and refer to the global variable directly, or change properties of the object instead, e.g. `store.type = "updated";`.

What is the point of this bizarre arrangement of functions anyways?

Comment: It should probably be a function in curried form that is lazily evaluated

Comment: this a small example of the problem described in [Issue](https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper/issues/52). I want to integrate two libraries.

Comment: @Matti Thanks for your answer. You directed me in the right way.